# How to replace values in a specific part of character with a range of numbers

Tags: r, for-loop, replace, lapply

I can't seem to figure out how to replace a specific value of the characters in my vector.
My vector is:

```
str(cryostick_1)
 chr [1:21] "4490015" "44900151" "44900151" "44900151" "44900151" "44900152" "44900152" "44900152" ...
```

The 4th until the 6th part of each of these values in the vector are "001". I need to change these all to 002 (until the end of the vector), 003, 004....until 137

Is there any way to do this with a for loop or lapply? At this moment when I even try to create a range from 002 until 137, it erases the first 2 zeros: 002 --> 2

Any help would be very much appreciated

Thank you in advance. This is how the output should look:

```
4490015
44900151
44900151
.
.
.
4490025
44900251
44900251
.
.
.
4490035
```

and so on until 137

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from the question, but perhaps you are looking for this:

```r
t(sapply(seq_along(cryostick_1), function(x) {
       paste0(substr(cryostick_1, 1, 3), 
       sprintf("%03d", x), 
       substr(cryostick_1, 7, 8))}))
#>      [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]      
#> [1,] "4490015" "44900151" "44900151" "44900151" "44900151" "44900152"
#> [2,] "4490025" "44900251" "44900251" "44900251" "44900251" "44900252"
#> [3,] "4490035" "44900351" "44900351" "44900351" "44900351" "44900352"
#> [4,] "4490045" "44900451" "44900451" "44900451" "44900451" "44900452"
#> [5,] "4490055" "44900551" "44900551" "44900551" "44900551" "44900552"
#> [6,] "4490065" "44900651" "44900651" "44900651" "44900651" "44900652"
#> [7,] "4490075" "44900751" "44900751" "44900751" "44900751" "44900752"
#> [8,] "4490085" "44900851" "44900851" "44900851" "44900851" "44900852"
#>      [,7]       [,8]      
#> [1,] "44900152" "44900152"
#> [2,] "44900252" "44900252"
#> [3,] "44900352" "44900352"
#> [4,] "44900452" "44900452"
#> [5,] "44900552" "44900552"
#> [6,] "44900652" "44900652"
#> [7,] "44900752" "44900752"
#> [8,] "44900852" "44900852"
```

or this?

```r
as.vector(sapply(seq_along(cryostick_1), function(x) {
       paste0(substr(cryostick_1, 1, 3), 
       sprintf("%03d", x), 
       substr(cryostick_1, 7, 8))}))
#>  [1] "4490015"  "44900151" "44900151" "44900151" "44900151" "44900152"
#>  [7] "44900152" "44900152" "4490025"  "44900251" "44900251" "44900251"
#> [13] "44900251" "44900252" "44900252" "44900252" "4490035"  "44900351"
#> [19] "44900351" "44900351" "44900351" "44900352" "44900352" "44900352"
#> [25] "4490045"  "44900451" "44900451" "44900451" "44900451" "44900452"
#> [31] "44900452" "44900452" "4490055"  "44900551" "44900551" "44900551"
#> [37] "44900551" "44900552" "44900552" "44900552" "4490065"  "44900651"
#> [43] "44900651" "44900651" "44900651" "44900652" "44900652" "44900652"
#> [49] "4490075"  "44900751" "44900751" "44900751" "44900751" "44900752"
#> [55] "44900752" "44900752" "4490085"  "44900851" "44900851" "44900851"
#> [61] "44900851" "44900852" "44900852" "44900852"
```

Or this?

```r
data.frame(x = as.vector(sapply(seq_along(cryostick_1), function(x) {
       paste0(substr(cryostick_1, 1, 3), 
       sprintf("%03d", x), 
       substr(cryostick_1, 7, 8))})))
#>           x
#> 1   4490015
#> 2  44900151
#> 3  44900151
#> 4  44900151
#> 5  44900151
#> 6  44900152
#> 7  44900152
#> 8  44900152
#> 9   4490025
#> 10 44900251
#> 11 44900251
#> 12 44900251
#> 13 44900251
#> 14 44900252
#> 15 44900252
#> 16 44900252
#> 17  4490035
#> 18 44900351
#> 19 44900351
#> 20 44900351
#> 21 44900351
#> 22 44900352
#> 23 44900352
#> 24 44900352
#> 25  4490045
#> 26 44900451
#> 27 44900451
#> 28 44900451
#> 29 44900451
#> 30 44900452
#> 31 44900452
#> 32 44900452
#> 33  4490055
#> 34 44900551
#> 35 44900551
#> 36 44900551
#> 37 44900551
#> 38 44900552
#> 39 44900552
#> 40 44900552
#> 41  4490065
#> 42 44900651
#> 43 44900651
#> 44 44900651
#> 45 44900651
#> 46 44900652
#> 47 44900652
#> 48 44900652
#> 49  4490075
#> 50 44900751
#> 51 44900751
#> 52 44900751
#> 53 44900751
#> 54 44900752
#> 55 44900752
#> 56 44900752
#> 57  4490085
#> 58 44900851
#> 59 44900851
#> 60 44900851
#> 61 44900851
#> 62 44900852
#> 63 44900852
#> 64 44900852
```

Comment: Yes thanks! Except how do i get it reach until 137? It stops now at 021 because that's the length of the cryostick_1 vector?

Comment: @DebbieOomen oh sorry, I thought the real `cryostick_1` was 137 long!  Just change `seq_along(cryostick_1)` to `1:137`

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some other already replied, but building on what I wrote before, this should do the job in returning a longer vector. It automatically generalize based on the length of the initial vector.

```r
library(stringr)

cryostick_1 = c( "4490015", "44900151", "44900151", "44900151", 
                 "44900151", "44900152", "44900152", "44900152" )

target = str_sub( cryostick_1, 4, 6 )
new = str_pad( 1:length(target), width = 3, pad = "0" )

newlong = rep( new, each = length(new) )

cryostick_1_long = rep(cryostick_1, each = length(new) )

new_cryostick_1 = str_replace( cryostick_1_long, 
                               str_sub( str_sub( cryostick_1_long, 4, 6 ) ), 
                               newlong )
new_cryostick_1
#>  [1] "4490015"  "4490015"  "4490015"  "4490015"  "4490015"  "4490015" 
#>  [7] "4490015"  "4490015"  "44900251" "44900251" "44900251" "44900251"
#> [13] "44900251" "44900251" "44900251" "44900251" "44900351" "44900351"
#> [19] "44900351" "44900351" "44900351" "44900351" "44900351" "44900351"
#> [25] "44900451" "44900451" "44900451" "44900451" "44900451" "44900451"
#> [31] "44900451" "44900451" "44900551" "44900551" "44900551" "44900551"
#> [37] "44900551" "44900551" "44900551" "44900551" "44900652" "44900652"
#> [43] "44900652" "44900652" "44900652" "44900652" "44900652" "44900652"
#> [49] "44900752" "44900752" "44900752" "44900752" "44900752" "44900752"
#> [55] "44900752" "44900752" "44900852" "44900852" "44900852" "44900852"
#> [61] "44900852" "44900852" "44900852" "44900852"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I think I should've been more clear though. I need the output to have the whole vector containing the next value. So the end result should be: 4490025, 44900251, 44900251, 44900251, 44900251, 44900251 and then when this vector is done it starts again with 4490035, 44900351........... and then all of these vectors underneath each other

Comment: Ok, could you be more precise about the desired outcome you are looking for? For instance, do you want a data.frame? A list or just a longer version of your initial vector?

Comment: i edited my original post and added the desired outcome.  Ideally a vector would be fine because we want the values underneath each other

Comment: Yes this is what i am looking for. But how do i extend this until it reaches 137? It stops now at 021 because that is the length of cryostick_1?

Comment: Well, you can augment the vector as much as you want by modifying `newlong` and `cryostick_1_long`. I assumed that 137 was the length of your initial vector.

Comment: Okay this i could manage hehe. Thank you very much! Have a good day